# Library for serialization of object including it's class so that it can be loaded by classloader and deserialized

Tags: java, serialization, deserialization, classloader, .class-file

Is there some library or tool which allows to serialize object including it's `.class` file? So when some application want's to deserialize that object, it can load it's `.class` first and than successfully deserialize the object even if that objects class wasn't on the classpath before.

I was searching for such library but couldn't find one. Nevertheless I was able to quickly implement simple case of such serialization library so I think there should be some mature implementation available.

Comment: I don't think normal Java supports this. But you could try to hack something together by serializing it as a byte array and then feeding it to a custom classloader on the other end. Of course your classloaders and permissions will be different.

Comment: Yes, thats exactly what I did. I'm just asking if there is already some more mature implementation available.

Comment: Some library offering this functionality. There are quiet a few serialization libraries but none of them offers such functionality.